# CKEditor removes data-target from <a> in Inline editor

Tags: ckeditor, editor, inline

Im using the Inline Editor of CKEditor. I want a link that opens a custom modal. So something like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#" style="background: #c21313; color: white; text-decoration: none">DESCARGAR LOS VIDEOS AHORA</a>
```

The problem is that when I load it in the Inline Editor it shows like this:

```
<a data-cke-saved-href="#" href="#" style="background: #c21313; color: white; text-decoration: none">DESCARGAR LOS VIDEOS AHORA</a>
```

Im using the Inline Save plugin that saves the page that I edit in a new File. In that File the "data-toggle" and the "data-target" part dissapears. So my link does not open anything.

Answer (score 0):

By default content placed in editor is [filtered](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html). That's why `data` attributes will be removed from final output. You can control what kind of markup is allowed to be placed in editor through ACF settings (Link with more information how to configure it you can find earlier)

[Here](https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/qYYdZx) you have some simple example how to configure ACF to pass through all `data` attributes:

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor', {
  extraAllowedContent: 'a[data-*]'
} );
```